# Музыкальный бот Discord

Tags: python, discord, бот

Захотел написать бота для дискорда музыкального, но есть проблемы.

Еще я скачал файл ffmpeg. Как я понял без него самого воспроизведения аудио не будет...
Помогите чайнику, могу исходный код прикрепить. Как я понял на втором скрине питон не видит класс, хотя я его объявил

UPD: прикрепил исходный код

```py
ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)
class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)
        self.data = data
        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = ""

@classmethod
async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))
    if 'entries' in data:
        data = data['entries'][0]
        filename = data['title'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return filename

@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, url):
    try:
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voice_channel = server.voice_client

        async with ctx.typing():
            filename = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=bot.loop)
            voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=filename))
        await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(filename))
    except:
        await ctx.send("не работает,зовите админа")
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы привести свой код не в качестве скриншота, а в качестве текста? Так будет проще и удобнее остальным разобраться в вопросе и Вами помочь

Comment: вроде сделал, как Вы попросили

Comment: я тоже сталкивался с такой проблемой. Попробуй посмотреть гайды мне помогло